# Get records based on Rowkey and ColumnFamily

Tags: java, hbase

Is it possible to read data from `HBase` based on `rowKey` and `columnFamily`. Currently I access records by rowkey by this code:

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "tablename");
Get get = new Get(rowkey.getBytes());            
Result rs = table.get(get);
for (KeyValue kv : rs.raw()) {
    holdvalue = new String(kv.getValue());
}
```

I want to add columnfamily as a filter to access specific records that belongs to that specific `rowKey` and `columnFamily`. How could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the column family as a filter by using the `addFamily` method of the `Get` object.

```
HTable table = new HTable(conf, "tablename");
Get get = new Get(rowkey.getBytes());     
get.addFamily(family.getBytes());    // <-----------------       
Result rs = table.get(get);
for (KeyValue kv : rs.raw()) {
    holdvalue = new String(kv.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works.. But I am having some other problem now, I should post another question in a separate thread.