# How to get an HBase row using just they key?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I have a question which my be very basic, but I am new to HBase. I want to get a row (eg. `[]byte`) using just the row key.

I am looking at the `Get` object, but the constructor expects the entire row: https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Get.html which says "To get everything for a row, instantiate a Get object with the row to get. To further narrow the scope of what to Get, use the methods below."

More specifically, I am trying to use the output from HRegionLocator.getStartEndKeys() to get the entire row.

Comment: The javadoc may be formulated a bit loosely but when you look at the javadoc of the constructor of Get, you’ll see: “Parameters:
row - **row key**”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records based on Rowkey and ColumnFamily](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236273/get-records-based-on-rowkey-and-columnfamily)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.Get` for this. Although the general Javadoc of the class and the constructor loosely speak of specifying the "row", it means "row key". You can find the specifics in [the description of the constructor parameter `row`:](https://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Get.html#Get-byte:A-)

> **Parameters:**
>
> `row - row key`

So the parameter specific the *key* of the row, not the entire data of the row.
With the other arguments to `Get`, you can be more specific about the columns that you want to retrieve from the row.